# Does non-standard analysis solve the measure problem?

Tags: measure-theory, nonstandard-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperreal measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257655/hyperreal-measure)

In every proof that the measure problem is unsolvable, the following assumption is made:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a=\begin{cases}0\quad a=0\\\infty \;\;a>0\end{cases}$$
But what if we instead define a measure $\mu:X\rightarrow *\mathbb{R}$ (Instead of $\mu:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$)

For NSA numbers, identities like $\omega\frac{a}{\omega}=a$ are well-defined even for infinite $\omega$; Therefore the examples and constructions of non-measurable sets (auch as Vitali etc) using the Axiom of Choice become invalid; Are there constructions for sets that avoid the validity of measures in NSA? Is there any further literature about this that is comprehensible for a undergraduate?

Comment: This is similar to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257655/hyperreal-measure

Comment: @IsaacSolomon I guess that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: What is the measure problem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the issue that there can be no measure that is defined for every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not sure if measure problem is the correct term for it?

Comment: I didn't see any references calling that problem by that name after googling variants of "measure problem."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just translated the german term for it word by word and hoped people would understand...