# What does Axiom of Choice know about when Creating a Vitali Set?

Tags: set-theory

An Vitali set $V$ is constructed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set by applying $\textsf{AC}$ to pick a single element from each of the countable equivalence classes in $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$, restricted to the interval $[0,1]$.

The interval $[0,1]$ is then reconstructed (and additionally as a by-product of the method of construction, with extra elements in the range $[-1,2]$), from these equivalence classes by forming for each element $q_k$ $\in$ $\mathbb Q$ restricted to $[-1,1]$, the disjoint sets $V_{k}$ defined as:

$$V_{k}=V+q_{k}=\{v+q_{k}:v\in V\},$$ where $V$ is the Vitali set, and

$$[0,1]\subset\bigcup V_k \subset [-1,2].$$

By usage of $\sigma$ additivity and invariance under translation of the measure $\mu$

$$\lambda (V_k) = \lambda (V),$$

we get \begin{equation}1\le\sum_k \mu(V)\le 3\label{1}\tag{1}\end{equation}

However, if in $(\ref{1})$, the countable sum is replaced by $\omega$, then $(\ref{1})$ could become, for example:

\begin{equation}1\le \omega * \mu(V)\le 3\label{2}\tag{2}\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}\displaystyle \frac{1}{\omega}  \le \mu(V)\le \frac{3}{\omega}\label{3}\tag{3}\end{equation}

As creation of a Vitali set via the use of the axiom of Separation isn't possible, then 'in effect' $\textsf{AC}$ is providing a 'supercharged' axiom of Separation to create the Vitali set.

Does this use of $\textsf{AC}$ mean an uncountable $\mathbb R $ sized "equivalent expression" could be thought of as being used in the axiom of Separation, which means in $(\ref{3})$ it can lead to the knowledge of very small number types (e.g. Surreal Numbers etc.) or to an extension of the Lebesgue measure to include non-standard number types?

Comment: The Axiom of Choice is just a sentence in the language of set theory. Much like Jon Snow, it knows nothing.

Comment: And there was me thinking that AC was like Lord Varys who knows everything (and much more than the axiom of Separation).

Answer (score 8):

What you are doing makes *no sense*. Cardinals and ordinals are *not* real numbers. If you want to think about them as surreal numbers, then you need to give up their standard arithmetic (in the case of cardinals you need to forfeit everything, in the case of ordinals you need to resort to "natural/Hessenberg sums" instead which tend to disagree with the standard arithmetic in most cases).

So there is no sense in moving from the sum to multiplying a constant by $\omega$. You're just mixing up concepts in a way that makes no sense.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila : Lectures on the Hyperreals, R. Goldblatt, 1998, Section 3.8, page 27, derives the expression: 1/ω=ϵ where ϵ is an infinitesimal and ω is an unlimited number. It says "The properties observed of ϵ and ω show that ∗R is a proper extension of R and hence a new structure". So in a hyperreal number system the expression (3) has meaning when μ(V) is replaced by ϵ. Similarly hyperfinite sums can exist. As a result does this not explain why a Vitali set is not Lebesgue measurable because use of AC for Vitali sets means that infinitesimal numbers are 'effectively' created ?

Comment: As I said, you're mixing concepts. (This is my gripe with modern internet-based education (see also [this.](http://karagila.org/2017/dangerous-knowledge-in-the-information-age/))) The $\omega$ used in the sentence you're citing is not the *standard* use of $\omega$ in set theory, and you would need to specify the context for it. Moreover, it's still not *the same* as just infinite summation and you're just mixing up concepts that have no business being mixed up.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila. The use of hyperreals in Vitali sets is discussed here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257655/hyperreal-measure.

Comment: And as you can see, it's not a very well form idea to begin with.